# Как кэшировать данные из <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, кэширование

Как кэшировать данные из `<select>`?

Как сохранять value из select в кэш и выводить их на другой станице?

Comment: cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage

Comment: andreymal, можно пж пример кода?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен не кеш, а куки...
SetCookie для установки значений в память браузера.  GetCookie для получения значений из памяти.
https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie
В статье описана установка и чтение куки

```
// возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=            
([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

document.cookie = "userName=Vasya";

getCookie("userName")
```

Comment: А можно пример кода?

Comment: нет встроенных методов `SetCookie` и `GetCookie`

Comment: Grundy, так и как реализовать тогда...

Comment: В ответе была ссылка, если бы вы перешли по ней, то увидели примеры кода, описание к ним и то как это работает. Если вы задаете вопрос, то следует прочитать ответ на него, в нем всё есть.

Comment: 1) Так и не понял как сохранять туда данные
2) Как указать в какое именно место страницы надо кидать данные?

Comment: Что значит "куда кидать данные"? Думаю, что необходимо почитать про куки в js, чтобы вы справились со своей работой.

Comment: У меня есть select. Как мне выбранные данные  закинуть в див на  другой странице? именно в див, а не куда попало?

Comment: Смотрите. У вас загружаеться другая страница. Функцией товарища @ЮрийБезруков вы берете в переменную `result` например информацию с кукисов. Дальше смотрите в сторону функции `innerHTML`, или же используйте библиотеку jQuery со всем ее множеством вариантов

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, также можно использовать *localStorage*. При выборе элемента списка записывать в него ключ, со значением выбранного элемента. Затем, в любом нужном месте проверять наличие этого ключа, и если он есть, то активным элементом списка ставить его значение.

Пример на **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d588gpat/)**

```js
// Выбираем на странице нужный select
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelct');
// При событии "изменения" нашего списка (выборе элемента) выполняем функцию
mySelect.onchange = function () {
   // Берём значение выбранного элемента списка
   item = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   // Выводим в консоль
   console.log('Выбран', item);
   // Записываем в localStorage значение выбранного элемента списка 
   localStorage.setItem('activeSelect', item);
}

/* ... 
   А где надо проверяем, есть ли в localStorage ключ activeSelect. 
   Если он есть, то значит ранее был выбран элемент списка. 
   Значением этого ключа является value выбранного ранее элемента списка.
*/

var activeSelect = localStorage.getItem('activeSelect');
// Проверяем есть ли такой ключ
if(activeSelect) {
    // Выводим в консоль
    console.log('Есть в localStorage', activeSelect);
    // "Активным" элементом делаем тот, к которого значение, как то, 
    //  что мы сохранили в activeSelect ранее )
    mySelect.value = activeSelect; 
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelct">
  <option value="1">Раз</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
</select>
```

И конечно, когда больше нет необходимости хранить этот ключ, стоит удалить его:

```
localStorage.removeItem('activeSelect');
```

Comment: Да, спасибо - то что надо. Только вопрос - как вызвать этот "item" в определённом месте другой странички?

Comment: @ArtemPro на нужной странице выбираем `select` - `var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelct');`. Фрагмент в ответе начинающийся с `var activeSelect ...` как раз таки и отвечает за проверку на наличие ключа. Хотя у меня подозрение, что лучше на стороне сервера такого рода вещи делать, но если требуется на клиенте, то так должно работать.

Comment: Да, го как я понял данные сохраняются в activeSelect а не в mySelect?

Comment: @ArtemPro Да, `mySelect` вы выбирали для того, чтобы навесить событие "onchange", а в `activeSelect ` хранится значение выбранного элемента списка. В ответе расписал более подробно комментарии для наглядности.

Comment: И брать в итоге данные из mySelect? Не очень понял - почему эта переменная будет работать на всех страницах, а та которую мы получили сразу - нет? И какой элемент под id "mySelect" ?